# Why do OpenImage's Image Label CSVs Contain Zero Confidence Entries?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, dataset

Looking at OpenImage's datasets, one can categorize the images using the image level datafiles. These are the files `test-annotations-human-imagelabels.csv`, `train-annotations-human-imagelabels.csv`, `validation-annotations-human-imagelabels.csv` and their machine generated versions.

Data in the files is of this form:

```
ImageID,Source,LabelName,Confidence
```

Here are some examples taken from the test-annotations-human-imagelabels.csv file:

```
000026e7ee790996,verification,/m/04hgtk,0

000026e7ee790996,verification,/m/07j7r,1

000026e7ee790996,crowdsource-verification,/m/01bqvp,1

000026e7ee790996,crowdsource-verification,/m/0csby,1

000026e7ee790996,verification,/m/01_m7,0

000026e7ee790996,verification,/m/01cbzq,1

000026e7ee790996,verification,/m/01czv3,0

000026e7ee790996,verification,/m/01v4jb,0
```

Some of the entries associate a label with an image but with zero confidence. But not every label is associated with every image with confidence 0 or 1 (this being the human version, mind).

Zero confidence implies the label does not apply, thus no need to have the association at all.

Why are some labels associated with a zero confidence?

Comment: a binary confidence value is odd. where is that data from? was it converted from something else? were any european CSV files involved? ... investigate.

Comment: https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/download_v4.html, section "Subset with Image-Level Labels (19,995 classes)", subsection "Human-verified labels". The binary confidence is AFAICT because in the human-verified versions of the files, people were asked to say YES/NO the image contains a given object. There are machine learning generated versions of the label files that contain confidence values in the range 0.0 to 1.0.